# Floodlight Controller socket error

Tags: python, jython

I am trying to run floodlight and but for some reason it is not starting and giving me socket error. As I am new to it please help me with this problem.

```
09:14:16.212 INFO [n.f.j.JythonServer:debugserver-main] Starting DebugServer on :6655
Exception in thread "debugserver-main" Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "__pyclasspath__/debugserver.py", line 69, in run_server
  File "/home/tashfeen/floodlight/target/floodlight.jar/Lib/SocketServer.py", line 331, in __init__
  File "/home/tashfeen/floodlight/target/floodlight.jar/Lib/SocketServer.py", line 350, in server_activate
  File "<string>", line 1, in listen
  File "/home/tashfeen/floodlight/target/floodlight.jar/Lib/socket.py", line 934, in listen
socket.error: (98, 'Address already in use')
```

Answer (score 1):

`socket.error: (98, 'Address already in use')` means that the port that you try to bind your socket to is already in use.

You can you [netstat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netstat) tool to find which process is using which port and than try to kill it, or you should use different port number.